# Flutter Huawei push by http

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

im trying to send push by http to Huawei Devices with Huawei consolé integration, but the documentation is confuse, and i'm not really sure how to build my body to send

I have this, but only works for foreground, if the app is in background or terminated, the push isn't working

This is the portar i'm following https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/es/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickapp-access-push-kit#dataDesc

```
{
    "validate_only": false,
    "message": {
        "data": "{title: Hello! 1, description: Hello, shirley!, params: { key1: test1, key2: test2}, ringtone: {vibration: true, breathLight: true}}",
        "android": {
            "title": "Hello! 1",
            "body": "Hello, shirley!",
            "params": {
                "key1": "test1",
                "key2": "test2"
            },
            "click_action": {
                "type": 3
            }
        },
        "token": [
            "IAAAAACy0irbAADqfnlY9pfEgoWWoIzgCBXQzPol8CTNzV6i3V5byP7cIhuU74vovAwysjkI_XMwowYj1sv5SrhXRi-sYXB5OrplLHEB02LO0pKHcA"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions received by the Push notification do not need to be run in the foreground.

According to the [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/es/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickapp-access-push-kit#h1-1582278779966),You can send push messages in either of the following ways:

Select target users in AppGallery Connect. In this case, messages can be pushed to both quick apps on the live network and those running on a quick app loader.

Send push messages to a large number of users in batches by invoking server APIs. In this case, messages can be pushed to both quick apps on the live network and those running on a quick app loader.

Conditions for a quick app to receive push messages are as follows.

[image]